# Ignoring prefixes in a JavaToken combinator parser

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

I'm trying to use a JavaToken combinator parser to pull out a particular match that's in the middle of larger string (ie ignore a random set of prefix chars). However I can't get it working and think I'm getting caught out by a greedy parser and/or CRs LFs. (the prefix chars can be basically anything). I have:

```
class RuleHandler extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def allowedPrefixChars = """[a-zA-Z0-9=*+-/<>!\_(){}~\\s]*""".r

  def findX: Parser[Double] = allowedPrefixChars ~ "(x=" ~> floatingPointNumber <~ ")" ^^ { case num => num.toDouble}

}
```

and then in my test case ..

```
    "when looking for the X value" in {
  "must find and correctly interpret X" in {
    val testString =
      """
        |Looking (only)
        |for (x=45) within
        |this string
      """.stripMargin
    val answer = ruleHandler.parse(ruleHandler.findX, testString)
    System.out.println(" X value is : " + answer.toString)
  }
}
```

I think it's similar to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559909/ignoring-an-arbitrary-prefix-in-a-parser-combinator%20*this%20question*). Can anyone see whats wrong pls ? Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should not escape `"\\s"` twice inside `""" """`:

```
def allowedPrefixChars = """[a-zA-Z0-9=*+-/<>!\_(){}~\s]*?""".r
```

In your case it was interpreted separately `"\"` or `"s"` (`s` as symbol, not `\s`)

Second, your `allowedPrefixChars` parser includes `(`, `x`, `=`, so it captures the whole string, including `(x=`, nothing is left to subsequent parsers.

The solution is to be more concrete about prefix you want:

```
object ruleHandler extends JavaTokenParsers {

  def allowedPrefixChar: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z0-9=*+-/<>!\_){}~\s]""".r //no "(" here

  def findX: Parser[Double] = rep(allowedPrefixChar | "\\((?!x=)".r ) ~ "(x=" ~> floatingPointNumber <~ ")" ^^ { case num => num.toDouble}
}

ruleHandler.parse(ruleHandler.findX, testString)
res14: ruleHandler.ParseResult[Double] = [3.11] parsed: 45.0
```

I've told the parser to ignore `(`, that has `x=` going after (it's just [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

Alternative:

```
"""\(x=(.*?)\)""".r.findAllMatchIn(testString).map(_.group(1).toDouble).toList
res22: List[Double] = List(45.0)
```

If you want to use parsers correctly, I would recommend you to describe the whole BNF grammar (with all possible `(`,`)` and `=` usages) - not just fragment. For example, include `(only)` into your parser if it's keyword, `"(" ~> valueName <~ "=" ~ value` to get value. Don't forget that scala-parser is intended to return you AST, not just some matched value. Pure regexps are better for regular matching from unstructured data.

Example how it would like to use parsers in correct way (didn't try to compile):

```
trait Command
case class Rule(name: String, value: Double) extends Command
case class Directive(name: String) extends Command

class RuleHandler extends JavaTokenParsers { //why `JavaTokenParsers` (not `RegexParsers`) if you don't use tokens from Java Language Specification ?

  def string = """[a-zA-Z0-9*+-/<>!\_{}~\s]*""".r //it's still wrong you should use some predefined Java-like literals from **JavaToken**Parsers    
  def rule = "(" ~> string <~ "=" ~> string <~ ")" ^^ { case name ~ num => Rule(name, num.toDouble} }   
  def directive = "(" ~> string <~ ")" ^^ { case name => Directive(name) }   
  def commands: Parser[Command] =  repsep(rule | directive, string)

}
```

If you need to process natural language ([Chomsky type-0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy)), [scalanlp](https://github.com/scalanlp/chalk) or something similar fits better.

Comment: Many thanks, this seems to work perfectly. Re why JavaToken and not Regex, no reason other than thats what I started with. Have changed to RegexParsers and it all works fine. As for scalanlp, yes it is natural language stuff I'm doing so will have a look at that now. Tks again